# Running regex search and replace javascript again

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var field1 = document.getElementById("field_lp_video");
field1.addEventListener("input", combineFields);
function combineFields(){
    var val1 = field1.value;
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var val1match = val1.match(regExp);
    var val1re = val1match[2];
    var oldURL = document.getElementById("changeThisMovie").innerHTML;
    var oldURLmatch = oldURL.match(regExp);
    var res = oldURL.replace("yeC3AisTs2Y", val1re);
    document.getElementById("changeThisMovie").innerHTML = res;
}
});
</script>
```

which takes a youtube url inserted by the client to the input field with the "field_lp_video" id and captures the video id only. then it inserts it replace my old video id (yeC3AisTs2Y) with this client new one.

**It works great!**

The problem is: I'm trying to let the client change the video as many times as he wants and that the same process will happen but now it will have to replace his last video id (And not my original first one) with the one he is inserting now.

So i tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var field1 = document.getElementById("field_lp_video");
    field1.addEventListener("input", combineFields);
    function combineFields(){
        var val1 = field1.value;
        var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        var val1match = val1.match(regExp);
        var val1re = val1match[2];
        var oldURL = document.getElementById("changeThisMovie").innerHTML;
        var oldURLmatch = oldURL.match(regExp);
        var res = oldURL.replace(oldURLmatch, val1re);
        document.getElementById("changeThisMovie").innerHTML = res;
    }
    });
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work. it's just giving the same video id again.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just trying to replace the video ID of one URL with the video ID of another right? In that case, you're going to want to use indexing on both regex results (not just one). Change the following line:

```
var res = oldURL.replace(oldURLmatch, val1re);
```

to:

```
var res = oldURL.replace(oldURLmatch[2], val1re);
```

That should do the trick!